# linux djvu viewer with tabbed interface

Tags: linux, debian, djvu

The Windows DjVu viewer (WinDjView) has a tabbed interface to open a few documents in one window.

On Linux, **djvusmooth** and **djvu4** open each document in a new window.

The browser plugin for djvu is ok if the browser supports tabs. But standalone solutions would be more reliable.

Does a djvu viewer with tabs support exist on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not aware of a DjVu viewer with tabs support. Neither Okular nor Evince has it built in.

However, there's an app called [Book Manager](https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/graphics/bookmanager) (uses Okular to display documents) that allows you to open new documents in tabs.

Another workaround, depending on your desktop environment, would be grouping windows.

If there really isn't a DjVu viewer with tabs support for Linux, consider filing a bug. For example, there's already a wishlist for [Okular](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155515).